# Kafka java consumer fetching only a few messages in a call to poll and sometimes none,Can someone help increase the poll count

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My configuration:

```
props.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
props.put("request.timeout.ms", 16000);
props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "4194304");
props.put("max.poll.records","3000");
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
```

ConsumerRecords consumerRecords = consumer.poll(100);

Comment: Maybe this post will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121746/4160889

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the consumer configuration `fetch.min.bytes` which defaults to 1 to ensure more data is being fetched at once. However, if there is simply no new data arriving at the topic after `16secs` (as set in your `request.timeout.ms` configuration) you will still see polls that fetch zero messages.

Here is the full description of the configuration `fetch.min.bytes` from the Kafka documentation on [consumer configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs):

> **fetch.min.bytes**: The minimum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. If insufficient data is available the request will wait for that much data to accumulate before answering the request. The default setting of 1 byte means that fetch requests are answered as soon as a single byte of data is available or the fetch request times out waiting for data to arrive. Setting this to something greater than 1 will cause the server to wait for larger amounts of data to accumulate which can improve server throughput a bit at the cost of some additional latency.

Comment: changed the configuartion ,fetch.min.bytes to 12500 , this helped me fetched 28k records in first call to poll but later in each and every call it is merely fetching 10-15 messages.I am new to this process,any suggestion will help me a lot

Comment: How much data do you actually have in the topic and how are you processing it in the consumer?

Comment: I can see 66K messages in my topic but as I start consuming the message lag becomes 0 but I haven't fetched any but then as new messages start coming to the topic I am able to pull them.

Comment: And how fast are you producing data? Looks like you are consuming the messages faster then producing them and, therefore, `poll` sometimes fetches 0 messages